# Keep powershell vocabulary in file and update it with only new data from source if exist

Tags: powershell, vocabulary

I have no Idea, is it possible and how.
I wrote one script that keeps around 1.5 mln. keys-values and growing day by day. Every script run, it parsing hundreds of JSON files to retrieve all valuse.
I would be happy if you can offer some Idea on how to export\import keys=values data from file and then just add new values from the source.

Looks like question to the air, but I hope =)

Comment: Could you give an example of said data source? I suppose you just want to add some data to the 'tail' of the file, do you need to validate if that particular k-v pair exists or just drop the new value in?

You need to define your needs more clearly :)